# call function with parameters in the Page Load .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm doing a filter form by 3 criteria, I'm having problems on the pagination since I do not load the data from the second page of the GridView, apparently I have to call my function that fills the GridView in the Load page event, but this function receives parameters that are the ones that the user enters in the search filter, How can I then call the function sending the parameters to that function in the page load event every time the page is changed in the GridView?

function

```
        public DataTable AdvertSearch(string tittle, DateTime datel, DateTime date2)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Util.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select*from table where titAdvert=@tittle or dateStart=@dateS" or dateEnd=@dateE;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tittle", tittle== "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : tittle);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateS", date1== "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : date1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateE", date2== "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : date2);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

search button

```
    protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        GridView1.DataSource = AdvertSearch(txtTitle.Text,txtDateI.Text,txtDateF.Text);
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

Comment: I can't understand your question at all. Could you disambiguate what you might mean by "page" as a web page and "page" as a block of data results? Also is "GV" a GridView? And also ask an actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a pageIndexChanging event to trigger the grid to be reloaded when the user clicks to the next page. Check out the code below:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{  
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;  
    BindData();  
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = AdvertSearch(txtTitle.Text,txtDateI.Text,txtDateF.Text);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And please write your code in english, as it makes it more readable for all programmers.

Comment: I already put that way but it does not work, when I go to the second page it does not load anything

Comment: @Ivxn I have added the Page_Load event code in my answer that will keep the gridview updated. Please try it out.

Comment: Now How can I control that I do not load data in the Grid View until I click on the search button

Comment: thanks , I just need to add IsPostBack so that the GridView does not show until the user does click on the button